# Can we use the same ms graph API to search files or documents in Sharepoint, OneDrive and Teams programmatically

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

MS graph explorer offers many APIs with code snippet to search over ms office 365 but I can't find API to search files and documents in Teams or all the files and documents in SharePoint, OneDrive and Teams are saved in the same place? so we can use the same ms graph API to search files or documents over them all?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Search API provides one unified search endpoint that you can use to query data in the Microsoft cloud - messages and events in Outlook mailboxes, and files on OneDrive and SharePoint - that Microsoft Search already indexes. You can search [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages), [OneDrive/Sharepoint info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files) etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have two questions, (1) how to search files or documents in Teams messages channels? (2)  is it correct that SharePoint and Onedrive have the same storage area?

Answer (score 0):

One method by which you could use Ms Graph Api to search files is by wrapping a try and catch around the GET request. On the try section it will check if the file exists (basically retrieve the file), if it fails or the file is not present it will run the catch section.

```
try {
 $drive = $graph->createRequest("GET",
  "/sites/".$siteID."/drives/".$documentFolderID."/root:/$path/$target:/children")
    ->execute();
}catch(\Exception $e) {
        "File not found"
}
```

Where $siteID can be retrieved from graph explorer using the following query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search={sitename}
```

Similarly $documentFolderID or the Document library of your site can be retrieved by the following query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/drives
```

Note: This will retrieve all the documents from a Sharepoint site/Teams

To obtain all files/folders from OneDrive use the following query in MS Graph Explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```